# Comparing user input to file contents with Java

Tags: java

I want to write a java code which reads a file having many sentences for example-

```
Hey how you doing?
Hi I am fine.
Hello World, Good Morning!
```

The user is asked to enter the first word of sentence as input and the output should be the rest of the sentence. For example, if the input word is "Hi" then the output should be "I am fine." This is my code below, I don't know what's wrong! Really need your help guys! Thanks!

```
import java.io.*;  
import java.util.*;  
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.BufferedReader;

public class FileContents {  
  public static void main(String args[]) {   
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader("myfile.txt"));  
    Vector lineArray=new Vector();  
    String lineContents=null;  
    int counter=0,i; 

    try {  
      while ((lineContents=br.readLine())!=null) {  
        lineArray.add(lineContents);  
        counter++;  
      }  
    } catch (FileNotFoundException fne) {  
      fne.printStackTrace();  
    } catch (IOException io) {  
      io.printStackTrace();  
    }  

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    int no=3;
    String[] textData=new String[no];
    for (i=0;i<no;i++) {
      textData[i]=br.readLine();
    }
    br.close();

    System.out.println("These are the file contents : ");
    for (i=0;i<lineArray.size();i++) {  
      System.out.println(lineArray.get(i));  
    }  


    System.out.println("\n Enter first word of sentence : ");
    String st = input.nextLine();
    String[] word= st.split(" ");

    System.out.println("\n Rest of the sentence is  :  ");

    for (i=0;i<lineArray.size();i++) {  
      if (word[i].equals(textData[i])) {
        while (word[i]!='\n')
          System.out.println(word[i]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm a beginner, so please excuse me for my mistakes.

Output from the above code - Nothing!! No errors, but no output either!!

Comment: We don't know what's wrong either--maybe you could help by telling us what happens versus what you expect. Also, if this is homework, please tag as such.

Comment: The first thing which is wrong is the indentation. As is, the code is very hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to understand what you are trying to do in the above code (might be my brain is not functioning due to lack to sleep) but you could do the following:

1. Get the user input and store it in a `String input`.
2. Read the file line by line as you did above but use `StringTokenizer` and tokenize each line.
3. Just compare the first token with input and see if they match.
4. If yes, print line; exit, else go to next line.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have got your input down, using your scanner class all you need to do is add a HashMap.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

Something along the lines of,

**Update**

```
HashMap responseMap = new HashMap();

public string genResponse(String word) {
   String response = (String) responseMap.get(word);
   if (response != null){
      return response;
   } else {
      return "Word unrecognized!" 
   }
}
```

You will need to populate your response map with your responses.

**Update 2**

This is how I would re-structure your class, I've omitted code as this is your homework.

```
public class FileContents {

    public HashMap responseMap = new HashMap();
    public Vector lineArray = new Vector();

    public static void main(String args[]){
        //Call function to populate the map
        populateResponseMap();
        //Read the lines        
        readLines();
    }

    public void populateResponseMap(){
        //This is where you would add responses, something like
        responseMap.put("Hi", "I am fine");
    }

    public void readLines() {

        //This is where you would read the data from the file using you scanner class

        //With each line you would call this function 
        genResponse(//first word in line );
    }

    public String genResponse(String word) {
        String response = (String) responseMap.get(word);
        if (response != null) {
            return response;
        } else {
            return "Word unrecognized!";
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: people, y u no use generics? Also this won't compile because you're not returning anything if response is null. Oh and a HashMap has a .containsKey(key) method so you don't need to nullcheck it.

Comment: @Zenzen: although I obviously agree regarding generics, doing a null check is more efficient than doing a containsKey, because it just needs one map lookup rather than two.

Comment: yes, but for some strange reason there might be a null value under a key and a simple get will not distinguish that ;)

Comment: @garyamoris -  I'm a beginner, sorry, I don't understand where to add those lines in my code. It would be great if you post the complete code with your lines added in it. Thanks again!

Comment: Well I shouldn't really just post an answer, however I will add an update showing how you should structure this. Remember to use functions they'll make your code so much more readable.